# Floating stops on resize due to horizontal overflow

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed-width DIV that floats left, with the main content just beside it. When I resize the window, instead of a horizontal scrollbar I see the main DIV jumping downward below the floating DIV, i.e. the "floating" effect disappears.

A demo is available here:

http://jsfiddle.net/rustamabd/Xygn2/

How do I tell the browser that I *always* want to see both DIVs side-by-size, but *without* having to set `min-width` on the main DIV (I want the tables in the main div to squeeze as much as possible before the scrollbar appears).

Comment: This is what happening: the table element has not enough space to stay on the right, so it goes below the left element. This table, because of its content has a default width, so you must set it to be relative (%).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it necessary to have two elements with class `"main"`? By changing the class name of your text div to `"mainBody"` I was able to get what you want with this...

```
.main-left {
    float:left;
}
.left-block-1 {
    width: 160px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: grey;
}
.mainBody {
    left:175px;
    width:400px;
    position:absolute; 
}
.body{
    overflow:auto;
}
```

So the html from the edited fiddle is...

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="main-left">
        <div class="left-block-1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="mainBody">
        Block-1
        <br>
        QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNMQWER
        <table>
            <tr><td>A B C</td><td>A B C D E F G H I K L M O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A B C</td><td>A B C D E F G H I K L M O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z</td></tr>
            <tr><td>A B C</td><td>A B C D E F G H I K L M O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z</td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, `overflow:auto` works! I don't quite understand why though, (1) what is the default overflow if not `auto`, and (2) what's the purpose of `position:relative` in this case (it works without it, too)?

Comment: Also how do I make the scrollbar appear at the bottom of the page instead of at the main DIV?

Comment: Overflow:auto does what you described and automatically adds the scroll bar when the div gets too small to fit what's inside. The default usually just extends the text outside of the div or gives you the problem you were having. And sorry, I don't think the position:relative is necessary there. I was just seeing if it would help and forgot to take it off.

Comment: Thanks. I accepted your answer, but ended up implementing this differently - simply with a margin, without floating ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rustamabd/Xygn2/28/)).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the layout responsive, you must use percentage unit. And use  `word-wrap:break-word;` to make the text go to the next line

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Xygn2/17/)

Otherwise, you need to use overflow:hidden; but this will truncate the word when it needs more space

```
.main{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Xygn2/7/)